# can I move available space from root (/) or other partition to home (/home)?

Tags: partitioning, mount

My Ubuntu 18.04 sits in my SSD (`sdb`) along with Windows 10 (`sdb1`) - `sdb5` is `/`, and `sdb6` is `/home`, respectively.

Here's the list of disk partitions - I removed the unimportant partitions out of the list (usb, tmp files, dev/loops):

```
edmond@edmond-OptiPlex-3020:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             8154204         0   8154204   0% /dev
/dev/sdb1      288560172  56928068 231632104  20% /media/edmond/8C2A50DC2A50C53C
/dev/sdb2          98304     29065     69239  30% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb5       93675036  15184700  73688800  18% /
/dev/sdb6       93700636  66995956  21901864  76% /home

edmond@edmond-OptiPlex-3020:~/opencv-3.4.0$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
[sudo] password for edmond: 
Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 77A09C52-A3DB-11E8-A01E-BA0DBED5B5AE

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048 577122394 577120347 275.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb2  577124352 577329151    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sdb3  577329152 578283519    954368   466M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdb4  578283520 593907711  15624192   7.5G Linux swap
/dev/sdb5  593907712 785313791 191406080  91.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb6  785313792 976771071 191457280  91.3G Linux filesystem
```

Note that `/home` is at the very end of the disk space. I can definately shrink `sdb1` (windows) and `sdb5` (`/`), but **the available spaces will not be contiguous to `/home`**.

I'm currently running a project that requires about 100+GB of database to be stored, and I'm looking to see if I can store everything within `sdb` (which is my only SSD) to improve the access time. I do have another HDD, but it's somewhat old and slow.

So here's my question: would I be able to extend `sdb6` (`/home`) space if I unallocate spaces from either `sdb1` and `sdb5`?

Comment: You can ONLY add adjacent space to a partition. You can resize/move partitions to make the free space adjacent to the partition you want to expand. You WILL have to boot from a "Live" USB Key/CD, and run `gparted` from there. See https://gparted.org/download.php But First, backup and test your backup.

Comment: @waltinator Then in this case, can I free up some space from `sdb5`, shift the current data in `sdb6`, and expand `sdb6`? Assuming that there will be a backup before shifting the partition

Comment: I can't tell. Are you using  Extended partitions? Edit your question and show `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb`

Comment: You can do all these things from a live usb with gparted. You do it one step at a time. Resize -> apply change-> move -> apply changes etc

Comment: Caveat: moving partitions can take a very (very) long time and may not properly finish. It will probably be faster and more secure to delete your current /home, reduce your / from 91 G to about 20 GB (after freeing as much space as possible, i.e. remove any non-system data there), and then recreate /home in the about 160 GB unused space. You will need to update the UUID in /etc/fstab with the new UUID of your new /home, otherwise the system will not anymore find your home partition.